# xcopy installation of Visual C++ 2008 runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, runtime, packaging

Is it possible to make my C++ application run on a machine without `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package` by simply including some dlls in the program folder?

I want to make my app as portable as possible and want to avoid `forced` installation of the runtime, so is it possible?

*I don't care about possible future runtime `.dll` update and other troubles related, I simply want to supply my app with everything that it could possibly need (on every `Windows XP+` machine). Did someone face the same problem?*

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this, either by including certain DLLs in the same directory as your binary or by statically linking as described below, but this defeats the shared library policies of Windows. If every single application developer did this, there would be dozens upon dozens of installations of the same libraries (which, unfortunately, there often are). In the installer, just do a check for the presence of the runtime; more often than not it will already be there anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you can link with the static runtime libraries and you won't need to redistribute any of the runtime DLLs.  Check the documentation or the Visual Studio help for details on how to link with the static runtime libraries.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ab187afb-3af0-44ba-a03c-dde9e5208a1a/

Comment: Static linking is the best way to go for maximum portability

Comment: Be careful, better know what you're doing if you have your own DLLs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but it's a little tricky to get all the dependencies right.  It's not quite as simple as just "drop msvcrt.dll in to this folder and go."  I've done what you're trying to do.  It's not worth it.

For reference, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291(v=VS.90).aspx)

If you want to balance keeping your code small and reducing client-side dependancies, you may want to consider statically linking to the VC runtime.

Comment: But doesn't it say (in steps for `private assemblies`), that I simply have to copy VC90 runtime dlls and that's all?

Comment: I second the comment: "it's not worth it".  I've gone through the process as well, and it is a big pain.

Comment: @Daryl Could you describe the steps please? Or at least what else do I have to do besides dll copying?

Comment: @HardCoder1986: I don't recall if I actually succeeded, and it's been quite a while since I attempted it.  I'm sorry, but I don't have any notes written of what I went through.  In the end I think I installed the redistributable runtime.  Since then I've switched to using static libs.  Rather rather ironic since it seems MS's intentions were to reduce DLL hell and actually made it worse (at least from this perspective).  Going the static route has the additional benefit of being able to run debug builds on systems without the redist installed.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Mischel answer is good(+1), but sometime you just need to have dll but still want to provide a unique exe in the end.

Then, tools like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) comes to rescue...